# xed tool starts Xcode 6 instead of selected Xcode

Tags: xcode

I use `xed` from the command line a lot to open projects and workspaces. Since I installed Xcode 6 Beta 1, `xed` always open Xcode 6 instead of the selected Xcode, even if the version of the tool is reported correctly:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

$ xed -v
xed version 5.1.1

$ xed MyAwesomeProject.xcodeproj
# Opens Xcode6-Beta3

$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode6-Beta3.app/Contents/Developer/
$ xed -v
xed version 6.0

$ xed MyAwesomeProject.xcodeproj
# Opens Xcode6-Beta3
```

Does someone see the same behavior? Has someone be able to avoid it?

Thanks.